# Удаление дублей в select multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Есть функция которая вызывает следующий код:

```
 $.post("index.php?mod=ajax&act=country_to_city", {vals: "" + options + ""})
                .success(function (data) {

                    $('#cities').append(data);
                    $('#cities').trigger("liszt:updated");

                });
```

$('#cities') это select multiple (select2)

data содержит html код

Проблема заключается в том что эта функция может вызываться несколько раз и данные в селекте начинают повторятся.

Собственно сама задача: Как удалить все дублирующиеся option в идеале в конце этой функции вызвать функцию uniq(element) что бы она удалила все дубли. Пробовал разные методы но ничего не помогло.

Comment: очистить селект перед добавлением - не вариант?

Comment: Создать массив, в который записывать имена и размеры всех загруженных файлов, потом сопоставлять

Comment: Очистить не вариант так как данные могут поступать разные, надо сохранить предыдущие.